# Separate Code blocks form text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have some text let say

```
hi how are you [code]a=b+c[/code] again some text[code]c= 7*5[/code] Now some text
```

output i want from this is

```
hi how are you 

`a=b+c`

again some text 

`c= 7*5<`

Now some text
```

So user can distinguish the description and code easily i am using coderay gem for showing code part . so i just want to know when to pass the code to coderay and when to show the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = "hi how are you [code]a=b+c[/code] again some text[code]c= 7*5[/code] Now some text"

str.gsub!(/\[code\](?!<=\[\/code\]).*\[\/code\]/) do |match, replace|
  replace = CodeRay.scan(match, :ruby).div
end
```

Comment: Your regex will not match `[code]x=[1,2,3][/code]`, but you could use this one: `/\[code\](?!<=\[\/code\]).*\[\/code\]/`

Comment: thanks for all you help . its solve much of the problem .i just have a little more problem with that. i replace [code][/code] with <code></code> and updated str.gsub!(/<code>(?!<=\[\/code\]).*<\/code>/) . now i just have a little problem with that. Coderay is working fine but still have the <code></code> also when showing

Comment: use '/m' for multiline match - example : /\[code\](?!<=\[\/code\]).*\[\/code\]/m