# Separate multiline Code blocks form text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

```
Description -as\r\n [code]a = b+ 4\r\nc= a +j\r\n\r\n[/code]\r\nagain text\r\n[code]a = c + 4\r\n[/code]"
```

output i need is to pass the **text enclosed in [code] to coderay for formatting.**
or you can say as similar to stackoverflow where **we can see code part and text part separated** . i am following [Separate Code blocks form text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352818/seperate-code-blocks-form-text) which is working if code block is with in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to avoid the newline problem:

```
str.gsub(/\[code\]((?>[^\[]++|\[(?!\/code]))*+)\[\/code\]/) do |match, replace|
   ...
```

The content enclosed between `[code]` tags is in the first capturing group.